# PHP generated table with user input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I am working on a little project for a clan of mine, we just want a little dashboard to track stuff from the game.

Now what I am looking for is to be able to put notes into my generated table where we can put stuff when members are on leave and such.

Can anyone help me with this, I am genrating the table with all the data its just the note that is not working out for me.

```
<div id="content">
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table100 ver1 m-b-110">
                <table data-vertable="ver1" id="myTable">
                    <tr class="row100 head">
                        <th class="column100 column1" ><b>Lid</b></th>
                        <th class="column100 column2"><b>Donaties Gedaan</b></th>
                        <th class="column100 column3"><b>Donaties Ontvangen</b></th>
                        <th class="column100 column4"><b>Donaties: Gedaan - Ontvangen</b></th>
                        <th class="column100 column5"><b>Kroonkist</b></th>
                        <th class="column100 column6"><b>Notities</b></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($data['members'] as $key => $value): ?>
                        <tr class="row100">
                            <td class="column100 column1"><? echo $value['name']; ?></td>
                            <?php if(intval($value['donations'])<150) {
                                echo '<td  class="column100 column2" style="background:red; color: white">'.$value['donations'].'</td>';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<td  class="column100 column2">'.$value['donations'].'</td>';
                            }?>

                            <td class="column100 column3"><? echo $value['donationsReceived']; ?></td>
                            <td class="column100 column4"><? echo $value['donationsDelta']; ?></td>
                            <?php if(intval($value['clanChestCrowns'])<20) {
                                echo '<td  class="column100 column2" style="background:red; color: white">'.$value['clanChestCrowns'].'</td>';
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<td  class="column100 column2">'.$value['clanChestCrowns'].'</td>';
                            }?>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="column100 column5"  id="verwittiging" placeholder="verwittiging-Test"></textarea>
                                <button type="button"  id="saveNote" onclick="setNote()">Voeg notitie toe</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code how I get the data

```
<?php
$token = "apitoken";
$opts = [
"http" => [
    "header" => "auth:" . $token
]
   ];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $test = file_get_contents("http://api.cr-api.com/clan/9QLUCV22",true, 
     $context);
   $data =  json_decode($test, true);
    ?>
```

Comment: where is your code for 'saving stuff'? All I can see is a data being retrieved from an outside source, with no ways of saving. Would you be interested in [Inserting Data into a MySQL Database Table](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php)

Comment: I am only inserting all this data once a week into php myadmin sql database, cause sunday on 11:59 it resets so we want to keep this realtime data the whole week. The thing is i want to add a comment on the right side of the table and I have no how idea how to stick it

Comment: well, create a table, that holds `week, year, name, donations, donationsReceived, donationsDelta, clanChestCrowns, note` columns. Then you can insert a blank data, every monday at 00:01, and finally when a note is submitted you can add it to the notes field of the year and week.

Comment: You need to mention the exact issue you might be facing. _not working out for me_ is too vague cause you didn't post any error or the `setnote()` function.